# How can I share same action logic between controllers with respect the repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I have CompanyController and DepartmentController:

```
public class CompanyController : BaseBackendController
{
   private ICompanyRepository repository;
   public CompanyController(ICompanyRepository repository)
   {
     this.repository = repository;
   }

  ...
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult BatchDelete(long[] ids)
   {

     var entities = repository.GetList().Where(item => ids.Contains(item.ID));

     repository.BatchDelete(entities);
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
}

public class DepartmentController : BaseBackendController
{
   private IDepartmentRepository repository;
   public DepartmentController(IDepartmentRepository repository)
   {
     this.repository = repository;
   }

  ...
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult BatchDelete(long[] ids)
   {

     var entities = repository.GetList().Where(item => ids.Contains(item.ID));

     repository.BatchDelete(entities);
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
}
```

You can see that logic of BatchDelete is the same and I want it place to parent controller, but there is a challenge, the repository. I cant call in base controller repository.GetList().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have some commonality in your repository interface. For example, you could this do:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetList();
    void DeleteBatch(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    // other methods here
}
```

where you have:

```
public interface ICompanyRepository : IRepository<T>
```

and

```
public interface IDepartmentRepository : IRepository<T>
```

Then you can set up your base controller like this:

```
public abstract class DataController<TModel> : Controller
{
    protected IRepository<TModel> repository;

    public DataController(IRepository<TModel> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult BatchDelete(long[] ids)
   {

     var entities = repository.GetList().Where(item => ids.Contains(item.ID));

     repository.BatchDelete(entities);
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
}
```

**UPDATE** Then your CompanyController will look like this:

```
public CompanyController : DataController<Company>
{
    public CompanyController(IRepository<Company> repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
}
```

This will do the trick.

One other note of caution it looks like your GetList() is getting *all* entites from the database and then select the one you want to delete for the delete operation. Better to retrieve *only* the one you are interested from the database and save significant performance.

Comment: nice! but i am in doubt how CompanyController ctor will be look?

Comment: I updated the above answer with the code for the CompanyController as well.

Comment: if I have specific method say in ICompanyRepository. how can I call it from CompanyController? I dont want declare it in IRepostiory

Comment: to previous comment: it will work if I explicitly hide the repository field in controller "private new ICompanyRepository repository;"

Comment: Don't make it "private new" - instead make the scope "protected" instead of "private" the base controller. This will allow you to access from the CompanyController for those methods that are specific to this repository.

Comment: in your answer "private IRepository<TModel> repository;" - so I cant access repository from derived controllers. And I still cant call specific methods in ICompanyRepository because according to your answer IRepository<TModel> passes to DataController - so the type of field "repository" is IRepository<Company> not ICompanyRepository, that is i get compile error, Any thoughts?

Comment: @eldar - In my last comment I specifically said to change the access of that to "protected" so that you could see if from the derived controller - I'll update the code in my answer to make that more clear. For your second issue, you can create a property in your controller which encapsulates it with a cast like this:

Comment: private ICompanyRepository Repository { get { return this.repository as ICompanyRepository; } }

Answer (score 1):

This, children, is why we pass services to Controllers, not raw repositories.